# Partial derivative of a two degree plane curve

Tags: calculus, geometry

Partial derivative of a two degree plane curve, with respect to x and y when taken, we get two linear expressions in x and y. If we equate it to zero, and solve them simultaneously ...we get a point.

Why this point is the point of intersection of the two lines represented by the two degree plane curve

Comment: Could you clarify your last sentence? You left out some words, and I can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: When a two degree plane curve represents a pair of lines, and we differentiate the given expression with respect to x and y ( partial ) and then equate the equations thus obtained to zero ... We get a point ( alpha, beta ) ... My question is why this is the point of intersection of the two lines

Comment: Z=x^2-y^2, for example ... We will get 2x=0 and 2y=0 ...so we solve we get (0,0) which is indeed the point of intersection

Comment: What is a "partial derivative of a plane curve"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's call your 2D curve z(x,y).  You know that dz/dx measures how much z will change if move a small distance in the x direction. If dz/dx is 0 at some point (x,y), then that means the curve is level in the x direction, though it might still be sloped in the y direction. So when you find a general expression for dz/dx and set it to 0, you are finding an equation that describe all the points (x,y) where the curve is level in the x-direction. Likewise, when you find dz/dy and set it to 0, the equation you end up with describes all the points where the curve is level in the y-direction. Therefore, the intersection of those two equations describes a point where the curve is level in both directions, and does not slope up or down in any direction.  Does that clarify?